# got this error org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file this error when select on hive

Tags: database, pyspark, hive

I'm are processing a HDFS table from the raw zone to the processing zone using Spark SQL. so i'm applying filters or conditions in the SQL query and then creating a DataFrame from the resulting query. then i write this DataFrame to a Parquet and Hive table. However, i'm are encountering an issue where one of the tables that you wrote cannot be queried in Hive:

`org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1` 
but the table can be queried by spark.sql

i expect it to be able to query the table on hive

Comment: I've experienced this issue when the table is written using Spark with `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat=false` (the default) and contains `decimal` columns. But Hive does not support the newer format.

We couldn't find any good solutions. So it was either rewriting the table with `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat=true`, or use Spark to read instead of Hive.